# How to update the propriety of a field objects in a firestore document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this database. I want to update channels 2 to false.

[image]
I tried:

```
db.collection('preferences').doc(user_id).update({communication:{'1':{channels:{'2':false}}}})
```

But as a result, channel 4 disappears:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the following structure with dot notation.

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("preferences")
  .doc("user_id")
  .update({
    "communication.1.channels.2": false
  });
```